# How do I access an element if the id which I want to access is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create elements and hence dynamically giving them the value. So if I want to access an element using a value which is stored in a variable, how do I do that ?

I've tried using `$("#'"+g+"'")` but it didn't work

```
var text1 = '<div id="' + g + '"></div>';
var text2 = '<input data-checkbox="' + g + '" type="checkbox" style="display:none;"/><h3 data-header="' + g + '" style="display:inline-block;">Timer' + g + '  </h3><input data-input="' + g + '" type="text" style="display:none;"/>';
var text3 = '<span data-minutes="' + g + '">00</span>:<span data-seconds="' + g + '">00  </span><button data-start="' + g + '" >start</button><button data-stop="' + g + '" style="display:none;">stop</button><button data-clear="' + g + '" style="display:none;">clear</button>';
$('#header').append(text1);
$("#'"+g+"'").append(text2, text3);
```

Comment: You're randomly inserting extra quote marks. Change it to `$("#"+g)` (P.S. try `console.log("#'"+g+"'");` and you'll see the problem. Compare it to something like `#header` on the line above in your code...do you see any single quote marks in that?

Comment: `$("#'" + g + "'")` is surrounding the id with extra `'`s. Remove those, and it should work (the selection part, at least)

Comment: $("#g") this is not working

Comment: @MiloniShah Look at my comment again. Is that what I suggested to write? Pay close attention to the detail. In programming, every character you type is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a small mistake.

You need to try like this `$("#"+g).append(text2, text3);`

```js
var g = "data";
var text1 = '<div id="' + g + '"></div>';
var text2 = '<input data-checkbox="' + g + '" type="checkbox" style="display:none;"/><h3 data-header="' + g + '" style="display:inline-block;">Timer' + g + '  </h3><input data-input="' + g + '" type="text" style="display:none;"/>';
var text3 = '<span data-minutes="' + g + '">00</span>:<span data-seconds="' + g + '">00  </span><button data-start="' + g + '" >start</button><button data-stop="' + g + '" style="display:none;">stop</button><button data-clear="' + g + '" style="display:none;">clear</button>';
$('#header').append(text1);
$("#"+g).append(text2, text3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```
$("#" + g)
```

The fact it's a string is already implied.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close to getting this right; the comments are trying to tell you that you aren't forming the selector correctly.

The selector for an id must be a string in the form:

```
'#id'
```

In your example you have too many `'` symbols, so the id from your variable `g` will be in the string, but surrounded by variables. If `g` was `test-id`, you'd have the string:

```
"#'test-id'"
```

...and jQuery can't match that.

All you need to do is take out those quotes, here's how that might look:

```js
var g = 'any-id';

var text1 = '<div id="' + g + '"></div>';
var text2 = '<span>Some other text</span>';

$('#header').append(text1);

$('#' + g).append(text2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Header is here</div>
```